# Show View Controller with Selected TableView Item and Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm trying to present a `SharkProfileTableViewController` from my `Main.storyboard` file with a `TabBarViewController` from a button action in a modal view in `Upload.storyboard` that has no tab bar.

The ViewController I'm trying to present is a selected item from a `SharksTableViewController` tableview based on the data from the modal view.

How do I show the `SharkProfileViewController` along with the `TabBarViewController`?

```
@IBAction func viewProfileButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let stb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBar = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! TabBarViewController
    let sharkTabBar = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sharkTableView") as! SharksTableViewController
    let sharkProfile = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sharkProfile") as! SharkProfileTableViewController

    sharkProfile.selectedShark = shark as JSONObject

    tabBar.selectedIndex = 3

    self.present(tabBar, animated: true) {

    }

}
```

TabBarController - the 'Shark' tab is the tab that should show
[image: TabBarController]

SharksTableViewController - when selecting an item in this tableview it presents the ...
[image: SharksTableViewController]

SharkProfileTableViewController - this is the view I'm trying to present (with the tab bar showing)
[image: SharkProfileTableViewController]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass any data to `SharkProfileTableViewController` that you have added in `UITabbarController` then you can access it using the `viewControllers` property of `UITabbarController`. `viewControllers` property will return array of `UIViewController` so you need to access it using subscript with your controller index in Tabbar.

```
@IBAction func viewProfileButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let stb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBar = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! TabBarViewController
    //If SharkProfileTableViewController at 4 position in tabbar then access it from array like this
    let nav = tabBar.viewcontrollers?[3] as! UINavigationController 
    let sharkProfile = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sharkProfile") as! SharkProfileTableViewController
    sharkProfile.selectedShark = shark as JSONObject        
    tabBar.selectedIndex = 3        
    self.present(tabBar, animated: true) {
        nav.pushViewController(sharkProfile, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Now you need to simply change index in `viewcontrollers?[3]` to access other controller from array.

Comment: this presents the Shark tab and passes the information - but the thing I'm trying to figure out is how to go onto the next ViewController.  The SharksTableViewController is the tab and the SharkProfileTableViewController is the next view controller when a specific shark is selected in the SharksTableViewController.

Comment: I added images of the storyboards to help show this a bit better

Comment: @pmanning Don't just add screenshot explain bit about what you want and give some detail about screenshot also

Comment: @Nirav_D I'm trying to present the SharkProfileTableViewController which is the next view controller presented when an item is selected from the SharksTableViewController

Comment: @Nirav_D It's throwing an error on the `let sharkTable = tabBar.viewControllers?[3] as! SharksTableViewController` -  Error: `Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10b5283c8) to 'Sharks.SharksTableViewController' (0x105e4e558).`  I'm guessing because this tab is embedded in a Navigation Controller...

Comment: @Nirav_D - so it presented the `SharkProfileTableViewController` again but again without the TabBarController showing

Comment: @pmanning Presenting the view always hide the tabbar try pushing the view, check the edited answer

Comment: @Nirav_D Ahh good to know! It worked. And even brought in the navigation controller back button which was going to be my next task.  Thanks for all the effort!  I really appreciate the time.